# How to add custom QWidget to the QMenubar as action which can be toggled?

Tags: qt

I have an Widget class as a QtPlugin. In my main application i want to load this widget and add to menubar as toggledaction, so that later if i close the widget i can open it via the Menu bar. How can this be achieved.

As this is not a docketwidget i cannot use the following:

```
ui->menuPlugins->addAction(dockedWidget->toggleViewAction());
```

I have tried something like this:

```
void MainWindow::addToPluginsMenu(QWidget *const widget) {
    ui->menuPlugins->setEnabled(true);
    QWidgetAction *ac = new QWidgetAction(this);
    ui->menuPlugins->addAction(ac);
}
```

An action is added but it is empty and cannot be toggled. Could anyone provide me a solution?

Thank you

Comment: In your `addToPluginsMenu` function your not using the `widget` member, why?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add toggled actions and keep them visible after an action is toggled.

Use the [setDefaultWidget](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidgetaction.html#setDefaultWidget) function

For example:

```
// Create menu
QMenu * poMainMenu = new QMenu(this);

// toggled widget
QCheckBox * poCbTest = new QCheckBox("toggle",this);

// set the toggle widget as menu action
QWidgetAction *ac = new QWidgetAction(this);
ac->setDefaultWidget(poCbTest);

// add the action to the menu
poMainMenu->addAction(ac);
```